# Python Twisted. Implement 'socket.io'-like events

Tags: python, events, twisted

Can't figure out how to implement custom events inside a Protocol

E.g. server-side

```
client.on('checkin', function (name) { ... });
```

and client-side

```
socket.emit('checkin',name);
```

My current thought is to make if condition depending on a data received in `dataReceived(self, data)` function. A kind of header stored in data.

Any suggestion or docs would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say "custom events" here, you're talking about implementing a wire protocol.  The "events" you're talking about are messages within that protocol, not things that you can do on any arbitrary socket.  I don't know what protocol `socket.io` speaks.  If you're writing the client (and it's not a web browser) then you might want to use [AMP](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/amp.html), which will give you an extensible way to do client/server communication.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you look on other protocols how they do it?

Eg. IRCClient would be good example I guess - http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/tags/releases/twisted-8.2.0/twisted/words/protocols/irc.py#L1707

Comment: Yes, AMP is the one I need. TY.

Answer (score 1):

you may not want to use a bare protocol for this,at least not with TCP.  `dataReceived` is called whenever the socket has data, with no natural divisions between "chunks" of data sent.  an easier approach is to use one of the classes that wraps Protocol, such as LineReceiver, which implements dataReceived and calls `lineReceived` ones its gathered a whole line of data.